# Can we create a console application in c# without Main() method

Tags: c#

Can we create a console application in c# without Main() method?

Comment: no, if does not have the main can be a class library but won't start alone like an application because Windows will not find a runnable entry point / method to execute to start it.

Comment: You have to have some method to tell it to run otherwise it wouldn't do anything. Do you want it to be called something different or do you have something else in mind for how you want to tell it what to run?

Comment: I'm not sure why all the votes to close as not a real question. It seems very clear what the question is and seems to have a very simple straightforward answer as far as I can see...

Comment: @Chris: It seems that down votes and close votes are more and more used to show a dislike for questions, even if they are clear and useful. Shame.

Comment: @Otiel: And now its closed I can click on reopen. I wonder if there is a "Don't close" option in the pipeline so you can vote against a closure before it happens...

Comment: Every questions is valid, there is no foolish questions, even that is valid. This question is very relevant after 9 years when the c#9 and Core 5.0 is released. Now we can do what the user is asking about : https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2020/08/18/c-9-top-level-statements-or-should-i-say-hey-wheres-the-main-method/. We should re-open this. @Chris I am upvoting for your suggestion

Answer (score 4):

No you can't:

> Every C# application must contain a single Main method specifying
>   where program execution is to begin.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

All executables in .NET need an entry point - this is a static method named `Main`.

It is required and without it you can't execute an application.

See the MSDN documentation for [`Main()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx):

> The Main method is the entry point of a C# console application or windows application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.). When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no instinctively as Main is the default starting point for a console application. That being said, what is the reason behind building a console application without main?
If you want something like that build a class library?

/J

Answer (score 1):

It's the program entry point. It won't compile without it. Compiler output for:

```
using System;

class Test
{
}

error CS5001: Program 'd:\test.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method
              suitable for an entry point
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, no you can't.

> The Main method is the entry point for every C# application and it is called by the common language runtime (CLR) when the program is started.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)